# Recieving Blank/No Response to Status Update Notification(statusUpdateNotification) from Apple Server - PHP v5.4.43

Tags: php, ios, json, server-to-server, status-update-notification

We have set up a URL in the app profile in iTunes and our server has cleared the ATS security criteria.

Following are the codes that we have tried to implement :

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$fp = fopen('appdata.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

We got no response with this code.

Then we tried -

```
$data = print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE);
$fp = fopen('appdata.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

We get a blank array in our 'appdata.txt' file as -

```
Array
(
)
```

Is there any way to find out if we are even receiving a response from Apple server?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we have solved the issue :)

While checking error log file we find this error message -

PHP Warning:  "fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given."

So we replaced this line in our first code -

```
fwrite($fp, $data);
```

with this -

```
fwrite($fp, print_r($data, true));
```

Now the code is working fine and we are getting the Status Update Notification every time.